# Android ScaleAnimation is on a View not moving the positions of the views below

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-animation

I am trying animate the height of a view on my Android app using the code:

```
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
                1f, 1f, 
                1f, 2f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, 
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setDuration(500);
mSearchHeader.startAnimation(anim);
```

This works well to animate the height of `mSearchHeader`, however,  I have a `ListView` control below my header. My expectation is that the height expansion of `mSearchHeader` would push down the listview (effectively reducing the listview height to compensate for the larger height of the header.

However, the listview's size remains static. How can I get the listview to "shrink" when the header is expanded? Do I have to add an animation to the listview also?

My XML is:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/buttonBackground">

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/provider_search_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_view" />

....
```

Answer (score 0):

`Animation` will create an illusion of animating, changing only the matrix of the `View` and not changing actual view coordinates.

Instead, use another animating APIs:

```
mSearchHeader.animate()
    .y(100)
    .setDuration(500);
```

This will both animate `y` value by 100 pixel and also change `View` coordinates, which eventually will affect `ListView` beneath it.

Comment: This doesn't look to move the listview down. The `mSearchHeader` overlaps with the listview. I have found how to get the listview to move down, however, performance is awful. I'll post another question for that though.